# What's the best way to loop inside a loop in NodeJS and Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a loop inside a loop in NodeJS and I'm getting kinda confused and results aren't giving me what I expect - sometimes callbacks are hit twice and so on. I'm using the async module, and it'd be great if someone could tell me where I may be going wrong inside the code below. If there's a better way to do this, I'd appreciate any tips.

```
it("should add some numbers", function(done){
    var typed_totals = 0, i = 0;
    async.each(arr1, function(value, callback1){
        var j = 0;
        async.each(arr2, function(element, callback2){
            testFunction(function(result){
                calculate(result, function(total){
                    typed_totals += total;
                    if(++j < arr2.length){
                        callback2();
                    } else if (++i <= arr1.length){
                        callback1();
                    } else {
                        done();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`testFunction()` in my case does a `http` request and gets some values. `calculate()` literally just adds some of these together.

If anything is unclear, drop a comment and I'll edit my question as needed.

Comment: what is `arr1`, what is `arr2`, what is `testFunction`, what is `calculate`, what is `loop`, and what do you expect the code to do? are both loops really asynchronous?

Comment: btw you never call `callback1` so regardless of what happens in the inner mess, you will never pass anything past `arr1[0]` as `value` into the iterator function of the first `async.each` (although you might call the outermost callback, `done`. you might even call it multiple times, depending on what the inner code does. usually you would wait to call the outermost callback until the completion callback of the outermost `async.each` executes. but you don't define completion callbacks for either `async.each` call.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm heading to bed, if you edit with more detailed info i may be able to provide a more specific answer tomorrow, here is an example of what my nested `async.each` loop would look like.

```
var async = require('async');

function addNumbers(arr1, arr2, callback){
  var typed_totals = 0;

  async.each(arr1, iterator1, function(err){
    callback(err, typed_totals);
  });

  function iterator1(val1, done1){
    typed_totals += val1;

    async.each(arr2, iterator2, function(err){
      if(err){ return done1(err) };
      done1(null);
    });

    function iterator2(val2, done2){
      process.nextTick(function(){
        typed_totals += val2;
        done2(null);
      });
    };
  };
};

addNumbers([1,2],[3,4], function(err, total){
  console.log(err, total);
});
```